# Jake on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jake

From what I have understood Jake (Rake equivalent for Javascript) is based on Rhino.

Does this mean that I cannot use it with Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Jake (https://github.com/mde/jake) is designed to work especially with nodejs. You shouldn't get any problems with running it.

Answer (score 0):

There's even an npm package; https://www.npmjs.com/package/jake .Jake and nodejs is a great combination for automation.